# Broken pipe error in CCL Lisp

Tags: stream, pipe, lisp

I am using CCL Lisp to run batches of experiments in parallel. On my machine, everything is running fine. However, I would like to use this on a server. When I execute this on a server, I always get the following error message:

```
> Error: on #<BASIC-CHARACTER-OUTPUT-STREAM UTF-8 (PIPE/7) #x302001C2725D> : 
>        Broken pipe during write
> While executing: #<CCL::STANDARD-KERNEL-METHOD CCL::STREAM-IO-ERROR (STREAM T T)>, in process listener(1).
```

My code always reaches the same point when trowing this error. An excerpt of the code is given below:

```
    ;; ... A really long function
    ;; write commands to processes
    (format t ".. writing commands to process ~a:~%" counter)
    (loop for c in commands
          do
          (format t "  ~a~%" c)
          (write-string c output-stream)
          (princ  #\lf output-stream))
    (force-output t)
    (force-output output-stream)
    (finish-output output-stream)
    #-lispworks
    (close output-stream))
```

I think this error occurs inside the `loop` statement, since not all of the `commands` are written to the output stream.

How can I further debug this and solve this issue?

Comment: I would propose to use the CCL mailing list for these specific errors. Also think of backtrace... See http://ccl.clozure.com under mailing lists...

Answer (score 1):

"Broken pipe" means that the process which is supposed to be reading from the pipe is dead when the Lisp process is writing to the pipe.

IOW, the problem is *probably* outside of Lisp. You need to see what is happening with the other process.

PS. You can combine your `write-string` and `princ` into a single [`write-line`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_wr_stg.htm). Also, you don't need `force-output` if you are calling [`finish-output`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_finish.htm) immediately.

Comment: He uses PRINC to write a LF. WRITE-LINE writes a newline, which on Windows might be CRLF and on Unix-like systems just LF. If the software is only running on Unix/Linux it does not matter though.

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Yes, I know. However, a protocol which requires a specific version of newline is broken, and I doubt there are many these days. [Unicode Newline Guidelines](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr13/tr13-9.html): "_Even if you know which characters represents NLF on your particular platform, on input and in interpretation, treat CR, LF, CRLF, and NEL the same. Only on output do you need to distinguish between them_". I think it is more likely that a person forgets about `write-line` than that they are intentionally coding to a broken protocol.

Comment: Protocols are not broken because they specify a certain lineend. Example: HTTP **requires** CRLF. https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec2.html#sec2.2  I don't think the W3C does care whether **we** think it is broken or not. CRLF is required.